# How to remove jquery/javascript on specific window screen width?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to know that is their any way to remove the external javascript at specific media screen size.

i have tried

```
if($(window).width()>786){
    $("#idofscript").remove();
    // and $('#idofscript').removeattr('src');
    // and $('script[src="js/crawler.js"]').remove();
}
```

but it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Code:**

```
function removejscssfile(filename, filetype){
var targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none"    //determine element type to create nodelist from
var targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename)!=-1)
allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
}}
```

**Usage:**

```
removejscssfile("somescript.js", "js") //remove all occurences of "somescript.js" on page
removejscssfile("somestyle.css", "css") //remove all occurences "somestyle.css" on page
```

**[Reference](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml)**

Comment: In removejscssfile("somescript.js", "js") filename is the full path which is given in the script scr="". or just the name of js file

Comment: @user3209470:just a filename.

Comment: @user3209470:can you crete the fiddle?